# Does eventbrite API support redirect to the previous URL?

Tags: eventbrite

I have a hyperlink button on my own website, and it navigates to event in the eventbrite. How could I close the eventbrite page once finish the payment or join the event and redirect back to my own website page opened previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now this is not possible on the Eventbrite Platform.

Maybe target a new page/tab on your button in the meantime?